# Can you sudo with input whiptail?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, whiptail

I want to ask your sudo password with whiptail password and then use it to run sudo script.sh this is possible?

I have tried this sudo command with the whiptail input for password

```
sudo -S <<< $psw script.sh

echo $ psw | sudo -S
```

Full Code

```
#!/bin/bash

#Password Input
    psw=$(whiptail --title "Test Password Box" --passwordbox "Enter your password and choose Ok to continue." 10 60 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
    #Password If
    exitstatus=$?
    if [ $exitstatus = 0 ]; then
        sudo -S <<< $psw script.sh
    else
        #Password If cancel
        whiptail --title "Cancel" --msgbox "Operation Cancel" 10 60
    fi
```

Comment: Isn't it bad habit to store passwords in environment variables? I know, with piping the password from "whiptail ..." directly into "sudo -S", you cannot check whiptail's exit status. But at least I would unset psw after piping it into sudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick check shows the script should work (works for me).  Your script is calling `sudo` separately from `whiptail`, so the two are not interfering with each other's use of the terminal.

The script should begin with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

because it uses the here-string

```
<<< $psw
```

Comment: I forgot to add the #!/bin/bash here. Did it work for you without asking again for the sudo password on terminal?

Comment: yes - the `-S` option worked as you had intended.  I'm using Debian which has dash as the `/bin/sh`, so (seeing the here-string), just added #!/bin/bash as a first step before testing it.

Comment: It should work even if I don't add the if right? like if I only put the `psw=$(whiptail --title "Test Password Box" --passwordbox "Enter your password and choose Ok to continue." 10 60 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)` and then I put `sudo -S <<< $psw ./script.sh` right?

Comment: The if-statement is used to check if there is no password -- and since the sudo would fail in that case, the if-statement is needed only to make a nice error message for the user.